# Blog posts have disappeared in WordPress site page

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

I'm editing the CSS of my WordPress child theme and something I have done has made the test blog posts I have made completely disappear.

I have tried backtracking to see which line of code has caused this but none of them seem to make a difference.

[image: How it looks now]

```
.fa.fa-cart-plus{
    background: url(assets/img/iconsspritsheet.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 17px;
}

footer { display: none; }

textwidget {display:none;}

.header-filter-gradient {display: none;}

.main.main-raised {display: none;}

.header-filter {display: none}

div.wrapper{
    color: #8393a0
}
```

Comment: Please provide HTML markup.

Comment: why are you applying display none for all the things, try removing display: none and make sure you dint messed up with any code

Comment: have you checked this in front end after saving it? Sometimes to due to some loading issues this could happen.

Comment: Hi. Please remove .main.main-raised {display: none;} and then check what happen

Comment: i'm applying display:none to the parts of the page i want to get rid of, for example the footer etc. 

How do i find the html for a WordPress page? I only have styles.css,function.php type files in my theme folder. 

I have saved it a few times and keep pressing F5 but nothing's changed.

Comment: Hi @YogeshGarg , thank you, that's brought the posts back. I was using .main.main-raised {display: none;} to remove the posts box on my homepage and that's come back now. How can i use it to only target one page?

Comment: @lomomeg please add home page class with this class to hide the post for home page.. Please check a class added in Body tag with name (Home) if on home page.

Comment: Thank you! That's done it, much appreciated.